# device or resource busy, despite that it is not mounted and nobody is using it

Tags: mount, umount

```
> sudo rmdir workspace/log
rmdir: failed to remove `workspace/log': Device or resource busy

>sudo umount workspace/log
umount: workspace/log: not mounted

>fuser workspace/log
>
>lsof workspace/log
>
```

Comment: what is the Full Path of workspace/log?

Comment: /home/mark/workspace/log  but I call all of this from my home directory so I use relative paths

Comment: have you checked with `lsof` as well ?

Comment: @Lawrence yessir

Comment: What happens if you run those command with *absolute* paths?

Answer (score 0):

A local guru told me, there is a program, called "netnsd" that may use a mounted directory, even though it does not show in fuser or lsof.  I need to ps -aux | grep myself and kill everything in sight that has to do with netns and the directory in question.

There is more, another case where that was not sufficient, he found that I need to kill anything to do with the process `Sysdb`